# instantiating ui-elements in onClick() vs. onCreateView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, onclick, fragment

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

public FragmentOne() {}

TextView matchStatus;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    Button matchButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_match);
    matchButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button_match:
            matchStatus = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_matchStatus);

            matchStatus.setText("sup");
            break;
    }
}
```

I realised that when I instantiate **matchStatus** in the onClick() method, I get a NullPointerException but when I do it in the onCreateView() method it works just fine. Could someone explain me why?

My guess is that it does not work in the onClick() method because it's connected to the Activity which holds the Fragment and it looks for matchStatus in the Activity and this does not happen in the onCreateView() method because I am inflating the fragment_one.xml but I am not sure.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your main view in `onCreateView`. So that you couldn't access it from onclick. In onclick you have use `view` which is actually your Button.

Use a global variable for view. Initiate it in onCreateView. Use anywhere you want.

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public FragmentOne() {}
    View rootview;
    TextView matchStatus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        Button matchButton = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.button_match);
        matchButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_match:
                matchStatus = (TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView_matchStatus);

                matchStatus.setText("sup");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help. This works of course but I also would like to know why instantiating just like I did it above doesnt work. Thanks :)

Comment: As your main view variable is in onCreateView method which is local variable. So when you wanted to access it from Another method(onClick) you got it null.

Comment: this makes sense even tho when I compare those 2 views, they seem to be the same.

Comment: Have you got your answer from this?